# Adding signature in Outlook email after .Body using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

In Excel VBA I want to create a macro to send a letter via Outlook.

I need a signature, but I cannot create it, because I have a `.Body` part and I need to paste a dynamic range of cells after it.

```vb
With newEmail
    .Display
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Body = "Good day" & vbCrLf & "bla bla "

    Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

    Sheet1.Range("G128", ActiveSheet.Range("G128").End(xlDown)).Copy
    
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Paste
    
    .Display
    .Send
```

What and where should I add, to add a signature after the code pastes the range?

P.S. `.Body` before the range is necessary.

Comment: Cristian's answer just have to be tweaked so that you get the signature file (which is just some html) file from whatever location your team's signature is.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new range in the Word document and call `Range.insertFile()` to insert the HTML file of the signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you construct a signature in the code and store it in a variable, e.g. Signature, you could do something like this...

```
With newEmail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Body = "Good day" & vbCrLf & "bla bla "
    
    Sheet1.Range("G128", ActiveSheet.Range("G128").End(xlDown)).Copy
    
    With .GetInspector.WordEditor.Range
        .Collapse 0
        .Paste
        .Collapse 0
        .Text = vbCrLf & Signature
        .Style = "No Spacing"
    End With
    
    .Display
    '.Send
End With
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add at the end .body = .body & .HTMLbody